# Is there a script that would identify records with spaces in SKU via PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: sku

Magento 2.4.5-p1

I am getting the Error when browsing products which I think has to do with the fact that some of the products I imported from Magento 1.x have SKUs with spaces.

Is there a script I could run that would identify records with spaces in SKUs via PhpMyAdmin so that I could then correct these right in the database?

Comment: Do not Do this from DB, Create a Script To fetch all products using product collection and check loop through products and check if product having space in sku's add that product in custom array then try to fix that manually or then you can create Db query for that product, first try that query on one product then do it to all.

Comment: @nihalmalik Oops - I didn´t see your note and I have made these changes in PhPmyAdmin. What kind of a trouble am I looking at? What did I break by doing this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please run this SQL query to identify SKUs that have space.

```
SELECT sku FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE sku LIKE '% %';
```

After that copy the SKU search in Magento2 admin and remove the space or update what you want.

or run SQL query to remove space like this

```
update catalog_product_entity set sku = REPLACE(sku,' ','');
```

Comment: Thank you for this - it works great! I´ve even used it to find records that have a dot in the SKU etc. but I am still getting the X Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state. Error. Is there a way to use your script to identify any illegal characters because I´ve looked and I just don´t see them anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Please run this sql query in phpmyadmin.

```
update catalog_product_entity set sku = trim(sku);
```

Ref https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54318/replace-space-with-no-space-in-one-column