# How to fix products when this comes up: Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state

Tags: import

```
Magento 2.4.5-p1
```

I have exported and imported products from Magento 1 into my Magento 2. Now, when I go to:

- Catalog - Products

and surf the products for example in the following way:

```
10 per page
```

Keep clicking on the right arrow and when I get to page **229 out of 237**, *it does not actually go to page 229 but instead stays on page 228 and gives the following Error:*

**X Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state.**

Some of the products had illegal characters in the SKU which I thought I fixed by using the script from here, searching and correcting this in phpMyAdmin:

[Is there a script that would identify records with spaces in SKU via PhpMyAdmin?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/369422/is-there-a-script-that-would-identify-records-with-spaces-in-sku-via-phpmyadmin/369425#369425)

But I thought I've tried all the possibilities for the illegal characters and the problem still continues. The issue is, I try to temp fix the Error by running the following command in my phpMyAdmin:

```
TRUNCATE ui_bookmark;
```

but when I try to access page 229 afterwards (by typing the page number into the box and pressing ENTER) - it doesn't go there and shows the Error instead so I can't actually see what products are on that page. **How can I resolve this?**

I've also noticed some of the problematic products (which didn't let me save them after making changes) appear to have part of the Custom options missing - like there is the first part for example:

```
- pick your wrapping paper,
```

then it has 'check-mark' as type but no defined options underneath. The only way I could save those products was by deleting those custom options.